# Можно ли создать тг бота? который будет беседе, и при полчение кодоого слова бдет писать с твоего профиля "я"

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Есть беседа куда скидывают предложения о командировки и  течение 30 мин пишут что они едут.
Можно ли создать бота который при появления слова "командировка и т.д" будет с твоего профиля писать "да я поеду" без добавления в беседу.

Comment: Можно, делайте 

Answer (score -1):

Можно бота оформить под себя, типо отвечаешь ты, а не бот, либо чтобы он писал "Я готов. Пишите сюда @username". Но чтобы с вашего аккаунта отвечали нужно иметь доступ к чату. А это нужен логин и пароль

Comment: В общем, через дефолтный aiogram или telebot такое сделать не получится.

Comment: Ну telebot и aiogram это для ботов, а тут скорее скрипт, который на определенное событие делает что-то